# Haskell function explanation needed

Tags: haskell

Can anyone explain to me why this function works.
I know how filter works it takes a predicate function and a list. 
In this def  maximaBy valueFcn `xs = filter isMaxVal` xs
filter takes isMaxVal as a predicate and xs is the list.
but i am having trouble understanding

```
where 
            isMaxVal xs = valueFcn xs == maxVal
Here isMaxVal is defined as a function that takes xs as an argument but how is that possible xs is an agrument of filter.
if we change valueFcn  to function length 
we get 
 isMaxVal xs = length xs == maxVal
if xs is ["cs", "efd", "lth", "it"] length of this is 4 but maxVal ==3 
 maxVal = maximum (map length ["cs", "efd", "lth", "it"]) ==3




-- maximaBy length ["cs", "efd", "lth", "it"] == ["efd", "lth"]
    maximaBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
    maximaBy valueFcn xs = filter isMaxVal xs
        where 
            isMaxVal xs = valueFcn xs == maxVal
            maxVal = maximum (map valueFcn xs)
```

Comment: For the record, there's a ready-made [`maximumBy`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:maximumBy) function already.

Answer (score 1):

Filter is defined by the notion that `filter p (x:xs) = x : (filter p xs)` *if and only if* `p x == True`. So it filters the input list to contain only the elements which satisfy the predicate `p`.

In this case, we define the predicate to be `True` only when its value as computed by the input `valueFcn :: Ord b => (a -> b)` is equal to `maxVal :: b`, whatever `maxVal` is.

On the next line, we have the definition of `maxVal` to be the `maximum` of the input list modified componentwise ("mapped") by `valueFcn`.

So in each case, we're viewing the input's value "through" `valueFcn` which produces some kind of value `Ord b => b` that we can compare. We look for the maximum and call that "value" (of type `b`) `maxVal` and then we filter the input list to contain only those inputs which match the `maxVal` with whatever `valueFcn` computes for them.

---

To be clearer, here's another way to approach the problem. We want to value each input by its output from `valueFcn`, so we fold those values in. Given a `valueFcn :: Ord b => a -> b` we write

```
let pairs = map (\x -> (x, valueFcn x)) :: Ord b => [a] -> [(a, b)]
```

And then we pass once over the list looking for the maximal value of the second component of each tuple.

```
let (maxInput, maxValue) = maximumBy (\a b -> compare (snd a) (snd b)) pairs
```

This is a maximal input and its respective value, but we're not done yet because we believe that this value may occur repeatedly in the input list, so we search through the list again looking for anything that matches that value

```
let results :: Ord b => [(a, b)]
    results = filter (\x -> snd x == maxValue) pairs
```

and then we return just the inputs which have gotten this far, not their `valueFcn` values.

```
map fst results
```

This method is actually a bit clunkier than the one your function uses, but it highlights in a slightly different way how the input values and their `valueFcn` values are connected.

Comment: Yes but  why can't i write like this
maximaBy :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
maximaBy valueFcn xs = filter isMaxVal xs
    where 
        isMaxVal xs = valueFcn xs == (maximum (map valueFcn xs))
       Still don't understand  isMaxVal xs = valueFcn xs
valueFcn xs =length xs (if valueFcn is length) but that is not same as maxVal.
isMaxVal xs Does this mean that list xs is an arugment of isMaxVal?
if so what does filter get as argument?

Comment: " we filter the input list to contain only those inputs which match the maxVal with whatever valueFcn computes for them."
But we are calling valueFcn xs? we are not calling valueFcn on the element of xs.

Comment: I understand it now.
problem was xs in the IsMaxVal i thought it was same xs as above